# Is $|x-y| > |x| - |y|$ if 1) $x < y$ 2) $xy < 0$

Tags: inequality

When you have a question like this:

Is $|x-y| > |x| - |y|$?

1)$ x < y$

2) $xy < 0$

Is there a way to solve this algebraically? Or do you just do scenario analysis with x and y being different combinations of positive and negative?
I'm trying to think if there's a more efficient way to solve these problems.

1) y < x

If $x=3$ and $y=2$ then $3-2 > 3-2 $--> no

If $x=3$ and $y=-2$ then $5>1 $--> yes

If $x= 0$ and $ y=-2$ then $2>-2$ --> yes

insufficient

2) $xy > 0$

If $x=3$ and $y=-2$, then $5>1$ --> yes

If $x=-2$ and $y=3$ then $5>-1$ --> yes

But how do you know something is sufficient? This may be a more philosophical math issue... but you've only tested 2 cases. How do you know for all cases that this is the case? Is there a more full proof way to figure this out?

Also, what are the best numbers to pick?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. If x and y have the same sign then |x-y| is the DIFFERENCE of the two so is GTE|x| - |y|. If they have opposite signs then |x-y| is the SUM of x and y, so is GT |x| -|y|.

Your original question should therefore be "is |x-y| greater than or equal to |x| - |y|?" Answer YES.

Answer (score 0):

On the actual GMAT, you want to try to complete the problem as fast as possible since you only have a set amount of time to finish the section.  Usually the fastest way to do this for the data sufficiency section is to test numbers.

You are right that (1) is insufficient and (2) is sufficient, because with opposite signs the difference between the two will be bigger when the total absolute value is of both together then separately, so the answer is B.

In general when testing numbers, its good to try both positives and negatives, whole numbers and fractions, so that you get the full range.